# How to modify the cat command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, cat

So I'm trying to show the contents of a text file with every occurrence of a particular word that is highlighted. I don't want to use grep as that only shows the sentences with that word in. I want to use the cat command.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Where are the words highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

I still suggest you use the `grep` command, and specify a big context value to print out lines "near" the matching lines, e.g:

```
grep -C 999999999 needle haystack
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will print whole file, and color only the matching text

```
   grep --color -E "PATTERN|$" data
```